Gear shaft with 2 different diameters
Where can i find a gear shaft around 6 inches long thats keyed and has a half inch diameter on one half and 3/4 inch diameter on other

Your post is effectively a shopping question, not an engineering one, especially as you've apparently determined that you need the described specifications. Consider to consult with a local machine shop or an online version.

probably from a machine shop
